# How to release my view from stack?

Tags: iphone

In my application I m using following coding convention to open my default screen :--

```
AppDelegate *ptrDefaultScreen = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[self.navigationController  presentModalViewController:ptrDefaultScreen.FrmFlashScreenLink animated:YES];
```

but when I move to other screen after default screen ,my default screen is still exists even i used [self dismissModelViewController:YES]; to dimiss default screen from view.

where I m wrong I want my default screen will be completely removed from view.

Is any other way to call default screen before actual application.
Please help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: @aman, just u have to put an image inside the bundle of the application and don't remember the image name should be "Default.png". It will take automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I use here is to make my default screen a subview of my main view. When I am done with it I either hide it, or removeFromSuperview it depending on memory constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just dragging image into bundle and don't forget name of image must have be Default.png. This image the iphone and ipad will automatically understood, the default image is an flash screen.